# Is studying probability (mathematics) halal?

Tags: halal-haram, science

Since Allah decrees everything.

> Quran 59:6 Allah has power over all things.

Is it correct to study probability?

If a dice is thrown the chance of a number appearing is always 100% decreed by Allah. Its not 16.67% as per probability.

Searching internet doesn't give anyyhing on study of mathematical probability.

Comment: Why would studying any subject be haram? There is no such thing as a knowledge that is haram to be learnt. Excluding Sihr (black magic) which might push the student into applying it. But mathematics probability? You're not gambling - you are studying the science behind probability. Even gambling itself is not haram to study - it is haram to APPLY. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Probability and math is human knowledge , it has nothing to do with god's knowledge. you have a probability of having a boy is 50% , but God already knows the result.

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet (pbuh) said:

> “What is halaal is that which God has permitted in His Book, and what
>   is haraam is that which God has forbidden in His Book, and what He has
>   remained silent about is forgivable.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 1726;
>   classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

While there are hadiths and verses which prohibits subjects such as Black Magic and other future foretelling such as Astrology.

> Narrated by Ibn 'Abbas: The Prophet (PBUH) said: "A person who learns
>   a part of astrology is as if he learns magic, and the more he learns
>   this, the more he learns of magic". By Abu- Dawud

However, there are no such hadiths or verses which forbids the subject "Statistics and Probability". Furthermore, Statistics and Probability is not classified under Astrology but is considered part of Maths. Mathematics is a well established and well respected subject.  Therefore studying Statistics and Probability is not forbidden.

Hope that's the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probability is purely epistemic. Even though Qadr exists (the universe is deterministic). Probability theory is still useful and accurate.

If we know that 30% of a land will have rainfall, but we don’t know where we are in that land, we say there is a 30% of it raining outside. Notice that there’s no actual luck or randomness here.